# I can't receive emails from my MT4 Platform

Tags: smtp, vps, microsoft-office-365

My MT4 platform sends emails with no issues (as per the Journal Log) so free (Yahoo, GoogleMail) accounts with no problem, but when I change the "To" email to my companies domain I can't receive anything.

**These are the MT4 settings I currently use**

[image]

I have closed and reopened my MT4 Platform. Its obviously an Office365 fault as there are no issues in the journal entries.

I also have this platform running on an Azure VPS.

In addition I have also checked my spam.

Does anyone else have a clue as to why I cant receive emails to my own domain?

Thanks

Comment: You're using the wrong port. You should be connecting to port 587, not 465.

Comment: Just tied this. I’m still not receiving any emails despite the journal a giving me no issues. I’m sorry but this is really making me cross now - it’s an email. If the address is correct then it should get to it destination. There’s no logic behind this at all.

Comment: If the mail was delivered to Sendgrid, then you'll have to check there to see what happened to it.